# Printing plots in julia from command line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, julia

I would like to print a plot on a screen using Julia language. I've already added Pkg.add("PyPlot") and Julia says that it has been installed. So here I have code, which I would like to execute:

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = sin.(x)
plot(x, y, "b-", linewidth=2)
```

But once I try to run it from command line like so:

> julia example.jl

it takes a while and then nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While in Python it's common to write a script, then execute it with e.g. `python example.jl`, this is not as common in julia. Instead you'd normally open an active julia session, then either include the file (`include example.jl`), open the file and run it with Ctrl+Enter in an IDE such as Juno, or simply copy-paste the code to the command window. Doing any of these will launch a plot window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to save your plot somewhere:

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = sin.(x)
plot(x, y, "b-", linewidth=2)
savefig("my_plot.pdf")
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me add that you can also add `show()` to make the gui window appear when running the script from command line. I.e.

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = sin.(x)
plot(x, y, "b-", linewidth=2)
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following function defined in my juliarc.jl
`` julia
function printpng(fig = current())
    savefig(fig, "tempplot.png")
    run(`lpr -PForsbergColor tempplot.png`)
    run(`rm tempplot.png`)
end ``

Where ForsbergColor is the name of the printer. This prints the current figure plotted with Plots.jl from my Linux machine.